# VB.NET declaration

Tags: vb.net

I have to declare `n = 01`. But whenever I try it's getting changed to `1`.

What should I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is just for display purposes then I would use the .ToString("0#"), unless you really need to do calculations based on two significant figures.

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 100
  Console.WriteLine(index.ToString("0#"))
Next
```

Gives you 
01
02
.
.
100